# Figuring out Sum, Product, and Average from User Inputs

Tags: python

I'm working on some homework which requires me to do the following:

> Write a program that receives a series of numbers from the user and allows the user to press the enter key to indicate that he or she is finished providing input. After the user presses the enter key, the program should print the sum of the numbers, the product of the numbers, and the average of the numbers.
>
> Run your program with the following inputs:
> **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8**
> **2, 24, 11, 1, 4, 10**
> **Enter no number**

Here is what I have so far, but my numbers are not coming out correctly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner so, if you could speak in the simplest terms possible, that would be great.

Take numbers from user until the user presses "Enter"
calculate the sum, product, and average of the numbers entered
display the results

```
#main program start
def main():

    #initialize variables
    count = 0
    sum = 0.0
    product = 1.0
    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")

    while True: 
        #request input from user
        data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
        
        #set up the termination condition    
        if data == "":
            break

        #convert inputs into floats
        number = float(data)
        
        #calculate sum, product, and average
        sum += number
        product *= number
        average = sum / number

    #display results
    print("The sum is", sum)
    print("The product is", product)
    print("The average is", average)
           

#main program end
main()
```

Comment: You can't get the average until you have all the numbers.... The sum and product should be correct, though

Comment: Also, you're dividing `sum` by `number`. You should instead count the numbers and divide by the count.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean the values are wrong. Nothing seems off except the average.

If you want the average, you need a list to collect the values. Try writing your algorithm by hand, and you'll see what I mean.

```
data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
numbers = []

while True: 
    #request input from user
    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")

    #set up the termination condition    
    if data == "":
        break

    #convert inputs into floats
    numbers.append(float(data))

# these can all be done outside and after the while loop
count = len(numbers)
if count > 0:
    _sum = sum(numbers)
    product = 1.0
    for n in numbers:
        product *= n
    average = _sum / float(count)

    #display results
    print("The sum is", _sum)
    print("The product is", product)
    print("The average is", average)
else:
    print("Nothing was entered")
```

Comment: I suggest checking if the input is valid float or int type before pushing to numbers list.

Comment: I thought about it, but that's OP's decision

Comment: You cant use `sum` as a variable name. Notice I used `_sum`, and it is below the loop, not above it

Comment: When I check the sum, product, and average with a calculator the numbers are way off from what the program returns. Also, when I enter no number I get an error message. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should `print(numbers)` after the while loop exits

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all the numbers since you are entering the numbers one at a time. It would be best to have the user enter a list like this:

```
def main():
    average = 0
    sum_nums = 0
    product = 1
    nums = []
    while True:
        data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
        if data == ""
            sum_nums = sum(nums)
            for num in nums:
                num *= product
            average = sum_nums/len(nums)   
            print("The sum is {},".format(sum_nums))
            print("The product is {}.".format(product))
            print("The average is {}.".format(average))
        else:
            nums.append(data)
            continue
```

It works by entering all the inputs into a list. The only way to exit an input is by using enter so if the input is nothing then it can only be the Enter key. Once the enter key was hit, I got all the values and printed them.

Comment: I don't think the assignment is asking for the sum,avg,product to be updated for every entered value

Comment: The values are only updates when the enter key is pressed. It is under the `if data == ""`, since that checks if the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Ah, yes. didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = []
print("enter key to stop")
while(True):
    num = input("enter a number :")
    if num:
        numbers.append(int(num))
    elif(num == ''):
            break
sum_num =0
for num in numbers:
    sum_num += num
avg = sum_num / len(numbers)
print(sum_num)
print(avg)
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the use case given int Question. Please double check your answer to the question.